# ACF Repeater Field: Using Functions for Links

Tags: wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

I am using an Advanced Custom Fieds Repeater field plugin for a block that has a link. However, there are two types of links for each block: an external link or an internal link (this one leading to another Wordpress page).

I'm trying to write a function that calls one or the other, depending on if the field is empty or not in the UI.

The one I wrote is not working and I'm wondering if I'm using it write.

This is the function I wrote.

```
    function mediaLink(){
    if (the_sub_field('block_int_link') == false) {
     echo the_sub_field('block_ext_link');
    }
}
```

And this is it used in the HTML.

```
<a href="<?php echo mediaLink();?>">
<div class="<?php echo $media_class;?>" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image[0];?>');">
<p><span id="headtitle"><?php echo the_sub_field('block_headline');?></span><br/><?php echo the_sub_field('block_description');?></p>
</div>
</a>
```

And I have the internal link set to Allow Null.

Answer (score 0):

the_sub_field works in a loop. You cannot write function to check the sub field.
And since repeater returns array of values, you need to loop to check if each link is empty or filled.

Here **repeat_field_name** should be substituted with proper **repeater_field slug** and **ID** is a **page or post id** in which you have used the repeater field to fill meta data.

Ex:

```
$rep_field = get_field('repeat_field_name','ID');
if( !empty($rep_field) && count($rep_field) > 0 ) {
   foreach( $rep_field as $r ) {
      if( $r['block_int_link'] == false ) {
        //echo $r['block_ext_link'];
        echo '<a href="'.$r['block_ext_link].'"></a>';
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm having trouble understanding what the ID is. The field name for the module I'm using is "media_block", so I got that, but the ID I'm not so sure. This module is also an include and get_field(media_block) has already been used on the main file so I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: ID is page ID or post ID.